# Numpy Uniform Distribution With Decay

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to construct a matrix of uniform distributions decaying to 0 at the same rate in each row. The distributions should be between -1 and 1. What I'm looking at is to construct something that resembles:

```
[[0.454/exp(0) -0.032/exp(1) 0.641/exp(2)...]
 [-0.234/exp(0) 0.921/exp(1) 0.049/exp(2)...]
 ...
 [0.910/exp(0) 0.003/exp(1) -0.908/exp(2)...]]
```

I can build a matrix of uniform distributions using:

```
w = np.array([np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 10) for i in range(10)])
```

and can achieve the desired result using a `for` loop with:

```
for k in range(len(w)):
    for l in range(len(w[0])):
        w[k][l] = w[k][l]/np.exp(l)
```

but wanted to know if there was a better way of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use numpy's broadcasting feature to do this:

```
w = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(10, 10))
weights = np.exp(np.arange(10))
w /= weights
```

Comment: Instead of calling `.reshape(10, 10)`, you can pass the tuple `(10, 10)` as the `size` argument of `uniform`.

Comment: Thanks.  I should have not just looked at the signature and assumed that `size` parameter is a scalar.

Answer (score 1):

Alok Singhal's answer is best, but as another way to do this (perhaps more explicit)
you can duplicate the vector `[exp(0), ...,exp(9)]` and stack them all into matrix by doing an outer product with a vector of ones. Then divide the 'w' matrix by the new 'decay' matrix.

```
n=10
w = np.array([np.random.uniform(-1, 1, n) for i in range(n)])
decay = np.outer( np.ones((n,1)), np.exp(np.arange(10)) )
result = w/decay
```

You could also use `np.tile` for creating a matrix out of several copies of a vector. It accomplishes the same thing as the outer product trick.